# Add parameter to a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add the parameter `delimiter` to a the formula
but not getting it or even know if it is possible

Thanks

```
function copyDown_multiTypeSubRoutine(delimiter){
  .
  stuff
  .
  .
  rngCell.offset(-1,2).setValue("deleteMe3");
  var originRange3 = rngCell.offset(0, 2).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(iferror(IF(AND(O2<>"", P2<>""), CONCATENATE(O2," & delimiter & ",P2), IF(AND(O2<>"", P2=""),Q2, IF(AND(O2="", P2<>""),O2,"")))))');
  .
  . 
}
```

Comment: Check your spelling - `dilimiter` vs `delimiter`

Comment: Thank you for that! but still not working

Comment: Note that there are two quotation marks that create a string, `'` and `"`. In order to use the value of a variable in a string concatenation, you have to access its `.toString()` method (either explicitly - `val.toString()`, or implicitly - `"text" + 1`). If the name of the variable is just present as text in a string, then it is not actually a reference to the variable.

Comment: I think the problem is your string concatination.  It should be CONCATENATE(O2,"' + delimiter + '",P2).  That is O2, double quote, single quote + delimiter + single quote, double quote ,P2

Comment: Thank `tehhowch` and `JheWizEd` that helped

Comment: @user777 If you've solved your issue, consider posting the solution & explanation as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you think others can benefit, otherwise consider deleting the question if you think it is not useful to others.